# Boot from Blu-Ray

Tags: iso-image, blu-ray, bootable-media

I'm currently downloading [Windows 8 Developer Preview with developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516) which is unfortunately too large for a normal DVD. Since I don't have oversized DVD's nor an USB stick with enogh capacity I'm thinking about how to boot that damn ISO.

Is it possible to burn a DVD ISO to Blu-Ray and can I boot from Blu-Ray images? That might be a silly question but my google-fu found no answers.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried before, but I know a [tutorial](http://www.starburnsoftware.com/help/burnbootablecddvdbluraydisc.htm) that helps you to make it.

Comment: Looks promising. In about an hour I will be able to answer my own question.. ;)

Comment: Nice, im curious to know if it works.